# Java Scanner reading line from keyboard and store in Stack

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How can i tell my code to stop recording when i hit enter on the keyboard?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ;
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>() ;
System.out.println("Enter sentence:");
    while (????)
    {
        stack.push(sc.next()) ;
    }
```

Comment: What do you want stored in stack? Each line as a separate element?

Comment: initially i want to try with a word, then print it out in reverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>() ;
System.out.println("Enter sentence:");

sc = new Scanner(sc.nextLine());

while (sc.hasNext())
    stack.push(sc.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this to **stop** recording when hit enter on the **keyboard**?

```
String input; 
    while (  !(input = sc.nextLine()).equals("")) {
        stack.push(input) ;
    }
```

Comment: @both, thanks for your help. what if i want to do the same for just one word i.e. store each char as an element?

Comment: use String class's toCharArray() function. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()